# Publish API to selected subscriber group or to an internal user in wso2 api manager

Tags: api, wso2, subscription, wso2-api-manager

Do we have any option of publishing any API to particular user/subscriber group which is visible only to those subscriber in wso2 API manager.

For Example - I have created an API - userValidateAPI which require to be used only by internal application team & shouldn't be visible to all. If application team login in store mode, they should be able to see this API & subscribe but shouldn't be visible to other subscriber.

Thanks,
Amith

Answer (score 1):

you can limit the visibility of api to roles.
On the first page of api creation, you can select visibility and put it to restricted by roles.

So if you want limit the visibility of an api to an internal application team, you have just to create an internal application team role in wso2 console(configure/user and roles) and write it when you create your api.

When people with this role will be connected to the store, they will see this api. But other people can't see it.

Hope I help you

Answer (score 1):

Visibility settings prevent certain user roles from viewing and modifying APIs created by another user role.

- Public: the API is visible to all users (registered and anonymous),
  and can be advertised in multiple stores (central and non-WSO2
  stores).
- Visible to my domain: the API is visible to all users who are
  registered to the API's tenant domain.
- Restricted by Roles: The API is visible to it's tenant domain and
  only to the user roles that you specify.

For more check [API visibility and subscription](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-APIvisibilityandsubscription)